# Center static ASP menu horizontally inside div

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I want an ASP menu to be centered in a div, but I am around it for some time now, and I couldn't find an answer that worked.

It centers the text but not the Menu.

```
<div style="text-align: center; margin: auto; width: 50%;">
    <asp:Menu ID="navMenu" runat="server" DataSourceID="SMDS1" Orientation="Horizontal" StaticDisplayLevels="5">
    </asp:Menu>
    This text is centered. 
</div>
```

The div is centered but the menu is at the left side of the div. I want it to be centered too. Sorry this is an easy one I'm just not looking at it the right way, little rusty on HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A mix of both your answers:

Add a parent div with "*text-align: center*":

```
<div id="divTop" style="text-align: center">
 <asp:Menu ID="navMenu">
 </asp:Menu>
</div>
```

Then add to CSS style sheet:

```
#navMenu {display: inline-block; float:none !important}
```

I think this is the cleanest way. I removed other attributes for easier understanding.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is having a parent div with "*text-align: center*" and a child with "*display: inline-block*".

```
<div id="divTop" runat="server" style="text-align: center;">
 <div style="display: inline-block">
  <asp:Menu ID="navMenu" runat="server" Orientation="Horizontal" StaticDisplayLevels="5">
  </asp:Menu>
 </div>
</div>
```